# Rescaling NDVI values 0-255 to [-1;1] using ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, ndvi

How do I rescale NDVI values that are 0-255 to -1;1?

I'm trying to do it in ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 8):

Using the raster calculator, you'll want to rescale your NDVI image. The formula you'll want to use is:

```
NDVI = 2/255*image-1
```

This is simply the linear regression between 0 to 255 and -1 to 1, applied to raster math.